# Quando eu for instanciar uma classe eu preciso realizar um 'delete' após o uso do objeto mesmo que a classe possua um destrutor?

Tags: c++, objetos, gerenciamento-de-memória, destrutor

Se eu instancio uma classe e gero um objeto a partir dele obrigatoriamente eu tenho que desalocar a memória daquele objeto no final do seu uso, certo? Mas se a classe que deu origem ao meu objeto possuir um destrutor será necessário realizar um delete no objeto mesmo que a classe com seu destrutor já faça o trabalho de desalocação de memória?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depende.

Se alocar no *stack* então não precisa, está é uma memória automática e o compilador gera código próprio que *desalocará* o que for preciso.

Se a alocação for no *heap* precisa saber se a classe faz isso por você, se ela fizer, não é necessário fazer algo a mais.

Se você escreveu a classe então precisa analisar se não é o caso de incluir dentro dela o gerenciamento da memória. O destrutor pode indicar que faça a liberação da memória, mas isto não é garantido, precisa ver a documentação. Se ela faz então você não deve liberar a memória manualmente.

Ainda se for no *heap* pode usar um ponteiro inteligente, aí ele se encarrega de *desalocar* pra você. É o mais adequado sempre que a classe deixar para o programador cuidar do gerenciamento de memória.

Se nada disso for feito, sim, precisa *desalocar* a memória sob pena de provocar um vazamento de memória. Não é fácil fazer certo em muitos casos, e mesmo nos triviais é fácil cometer algum deslize.

Comment: Quando minha classe pussui um construtor eu sou obrigado ou recomendado a usar um destrutor?

Comment: Não há nada disto, o destrutor só deve ser criado quando há necessidade. Na verdade boa parte das classes não possuem destrutor. Em geral isto ocorre apenas quando ela mesma faz uma alocação no *heap* e/ou abre algum recurso externo.